# Is it possible to save per application settings without admin rights (cross platform)

Tags: permissions, settings

I want to write an application that saves some shared settings on the local computer. But the problem is that anyone, including guests, should be able to use it.

So if a guest runs this application, it should be able to write data to persistent storage where everyone has r/w permissions.

The application can be launched from read-only media. So executable local files are off limits.

Do modern OSes support such scenario? Windows is supposed to have "All Users\Application Data", but it seems to be a junction point of some sort on W7, with weird permissions.

No idea about Linux and Mac at all.